# Is there a way to map a role to linked server login in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

Couldn't find anything online about this, but I'd like to give a SQL Server role access to a linked server using a specific login to that server. I know you can assign a specific local login to a linked server login with `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` but I'm not looking to do this for every login (nor am I looking for a script to do it for every login). I suppose there's some security reasons to prefer the use of an account, but I'd like to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly possible, no.

To manage group-wise access, you're supposed to use the **Be made using the login's current security context** option (doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#SSMSProcedure)).  Then, if you're authenticating with Windows authentication, configure the login and user and security access on the remote server with a Windows group that your users are a member of.  (If you were using SQL authentication, you'd need to have a login with an identical password on both servers to use this context.)  Then you'd have to create the role on the remote server, assign permissions to that role, and assign the group to that role.

This is kind of a pain, but it does mean that no matter how your Windows users connect to the second server, they'll get the same access.

Comment: The linked server is not a sql server instance.  This won't work

Comment: @JimSosa You really ought to specify that in the question, but there's nothing particularly different about the answer.  If your remote RDBMS or SQL provider doesn't support Windows Authentication or the systems don't have matching usernames and passwords, and you choose not to write a script or stored procedure to execute `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` automatically, then you get to manage the mapping manually.

Comment: And if the linked server is in a different network (which is detached from the main server's Active Directory) this won't work either.